# Does HATEOAS increase the number of calls to server?

Tags: web-services, rest, soa, hateoas, hypermedia

I have never used HATEOAS with RESTAPI's and what I understand is with HATEOAS, one doesn't need to store URI's and server send's the URI's in the response which can be used to fetch other resources or related resources.

But with HATEOAS, aren't we increasing the number of calls?
If I want to fetch customer-order information and if I first fetch customer information and get URI for it's orders dynamically, isn't it an extra call?

Loose coupling can be understood but I do not understand the exact use of this Maturity level of REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should HATEOAS increase the number of required requests? Without the service returning URIs the client can use to perform a state trransition (gather further information, invoke some tasks, ...) the client has to have some knowledge on how to build a URI itself (hence it is tightly coupled to the service) though the client still needs to invoke the endpoint on the server side. So HATEOAS just moves the knowledge on how to generate the URI from client to server.

Usually a further request sent to the server isn't really an issue as each call should be stateless anyway. If you have a load-balanced server structure, the additional request does not really have a noticable prerformance impact on the server.

If you do care about the number of requests issued by a client to the server (for whatever reason) you might have a look at i.e. [HAL JSON](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) where you can embed the content of sub-resources, though in the case of customer orders this might also have a significant performance impact as if users may have plenty of issued orders stored the response might be quite huge and the client has to administer all of the data even though it might not use it. Usually instead of embedding lots of list items within a response the service will point the client to a URI where the client can learn how to retrieve these information if needed. Often this kind of URIs provide a pageable view on the data (like orders placed by a customer).

While a pageable request for sure increase the number or requests handled by the service, overall performance will increase though as the service does not have to return the whole order-data to the client and therefore reduce the load on the backing DB as well as shrinking the actual response content length.

To sum my post up, HATEOAS is intended to move the logic of creating URIs to invoke from clients to servers and therefore decouple clients from services further. The number of actual requests clients have to issue isn't tide to HATEOAS but to the overall API design and the requirements of the client.

Comment: Okay! As the URI's are generated by server and they are not statically maintained by client, I was of the opinion that to fetch some customer information, we might need to traverse through some extra calls until we get that infomation URI from server in the response in which case, we hit the URI and get our resource.